# If 1% of total water in earth evaporates to the atmosphere due to Global Warming, what will happen?

Tags: angular-momentum, earth, atmospheric-science, geophysics

My views

1. Atmospheric volume increases.
2. Mesosphere's temperature will increase. Resulting **no rainfall**.
3. Some H<sub>2</sub>O molecules will escape to the space.
4. Rotation of Earth will slow down, resulting the Equatorial Radius will reduced & Polar Radius will increase.

What is your opinion?

Comment: Anyone who says "Yeah, but it's a *dry* heat" will be attacked by an angry mob?

Comment: @dmckee I am researching on new vision of earth, but i am learning, please explain & take it seriously.

Comment: Are these quantitative predictions based on mathematical models or just guesses?

Comment: @march Serious studies on Earth, Geo Physics & Calculations.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1593 "The ultimate climate emergency is a "runaway greenhouse": a hot and water vapour rich atmosphere limits the emission of thermal radiation to space, causing runaway warming. Warming ceases only once the surface reaches ~1400K and emits radiation in the near-infrared, where water is not a good greenhouse gas. This would evaporate the entire ocean and exterminate all planetary life. Venus experienced a runaway greenhouse in the past, and we expect that Earth will in around 2 billion years as solar luminosity increases."

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: Four comments: (1) You are missing a possibility, which is that water vapor migrates to the stratosphere, where it undergoes photodissociation and some of the the hydrogen escapes. H$_2$O won't escape, but hydrogen will. (2) This is a ridiculously large amount of water. (3) Despite being ridiculously large, this is the ultimate fate of the Earth, 500 million to 2500 million years from now as the Sun gets ever more luminous; the time until this sad demise depends on which papers one reads. (4) This is a "wet greenhouse" (as opposed to a "runaway greenhouse").

Comment: @Count Iblis thank you for your reply. I am trying to find out, if by any means the rotation of earth will slow down, will it speed back up again? this is my research topic, please help.

Comment: @DavidHammen thank you for your reply, but i think it will be only 500 years, because of global warming.

Comment: @DebasisChakrabarty - Did you read the first answer? It ends with *This level of global warming will take a bit of justification, I'm afraid.* That's an understatement. Even the most alarming of global warming predictions suggest a surface temperature increase of 20 C, and that level of warming makes some rather unrealistic assumptions. Evaporating 1% of the Earth's water would require a 100+ C increase. That won't happen in 500 years. Maybe in 500 million years.

Answer (score 3):

As Dirk Bruere has pointed out, the mass of the earth's oceans is 1400/5 times the mass of the earth's atmosphere. If 1% of that mass is converted to vapor (and not immediately precipitated out), this implies a mass of water vapor 1400/500 times the mass of the atmosphere, or 2.8 times greater. Ignoring the slight change in gravitational attraction of the earth with changing altitude, this implies the vapor will produce a pressure of 2.8 x 14.7 psi, or about 41 psi, for a total atmospheric pressure at sea level of about 56 psi.

From http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-vapor-saturation-pressure-air-d_689.html[image]

a quick reading shows that the surface temperature of the earth will be approximately 280 F (~138 C). Note that this temperature is not caused by the presence of the water vapor - it is the temperature required to produce a 1% evaporation in the first place. And, of course, since the atmosphere gets cooler with increasing altititude, the surface temperature will have to be even higher than this estimate establishes. It's true that the temperature increase needed will be augmented by the increased greenhouse effect of all that water vapor.

This level of global warming will take a bit of justification, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Earth's atmosphere = 5 x 10^18 kg

Earth's oceans = 1.4 x 10^21 kg

So if 1% of the water became atmosphere the pressure would likely increase by about a factor of 3 or so. Probably not survivable given the temperature this would require